# LINQ query - null date

Tags: linq

Ive a simple linq query to return records with a null date field,
just want to check the synatx of the "where" line is ok

var query2 = from cs in db.tblCases
                             where cs.date_closed == null
etc, etc,

thanks again

DD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would be careful with using null, I have seen issues with linq not generating the correct sytnax (ex IS NULL vs ==null)

I would recommend

`var query2 = from cs in db.tblCases where !cs.date_closed.HasValue etc, etc,`

Comment: I tried the !cs.date_closed.HasValue suggestion and nothing was returned, if i run a query in sql server:
select * from tblCases
where date_closed is NULL
I get results...

Comment: I would do a quick test and make sure it is generating the right SQL.  

`var query = (from cs in db.tblCases where !cs.date_closed.HasValue);
 Console.WriteLine((query as ObjectQuery<tblCases >).ToTraceString());`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `date_closed` property is of a nullable type, e.g. `Nullable<DateTime>` aka `DateTime?`, that should be fine.