# C# compare sql datetime to null

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating something in ASP.NET MVC 4 and in one of my tables there is a field of type `datetime`. This field is defaulted to null until it is updated. I am trying select from this table the rows that have this field as null but my LINQ query always returns nothing. This is my query.

```
from m in this._db.MessageReadStates
where m.UserName == name
      && m.ReadDate == null
select m
```

I new to C# so is there a correct way to check for null?

Comment: What is the .NET type of `ReadDate`? `DateTime` or `DateTime?`

Comment: looks like this post solves ur problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509044/linq-query-null-date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to check the `HasValue` property of the `Nullable<DateTime>` type:

```
&& !m.ReadDate.HasValue
```

Comment: Results in this warning - The given expression is never of the provided ('System.DBNull')

Comment: Edited in response to your clarification of the type in the question comments.