# linq to sql join with multiple conditions

Tags: linq-to-sql

I know we achieve multiple conditions in a join by using anonymous classes, but can anyone please confirm that below method won't work? Doesn't seem to and I am having tough time verifying.

```
    ...
join up in db.UserProfiles on
new { UserId = uf.UserId, IsDeleted = false, IsApproved = true } equals
new { UserId = up.UserId, IsDeleted = up.IsDeleted ?? false, IsApproved = up.aspnet_User.aspnet_Membership.IsApproved }
```

Comment: I know we achieve multiple conditions in a join by using anonymous classes => seems like a complicated approach to me. Why are you using || and && in the conditions?

Comment: @Pleun ??? Am I missing something? I am not using || and && there right? that ?? is to achieve a coalesce(). And join by using anonymous classes is because I am a sql guy and am trying to subconsciously mimic it in my linq? I just felt uncomfortable adding more and more main joins and thought above is somehow more 'efficient' though I don't really know. That's one of my beefs with Linq. It's a hassle to go check what sql it produces for each and every sql qry it generates and try to optimize it.

Comment: What is the result you want to achieve in plain english? All userprofiles that are approved and not deleted or ...

Comment: Most sql linq generates is pretty ok and equal or better compared to what most programmers will create (Except sql guru's,ok). Just be careful for the n+1 effect when Linq lazy loading creates a lot of individual queries instead of one join.

Comment: @Pleun - I wanted to know if giving 'constant' attributes is ok with anonymous classes in linq joins. It wasn't complaining, but wasn't returning what I expected. Yes I want all user profiles that are approved and not not deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, 'constant' Attributes in anonymous classes in a linq to sql join is valid and does bring expected results. The root cause of unexpected behavior I noticed is a totally different issue - [Described Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426765/linq-to-sql-multiple-foreign-keys-to-same-primary-key-visual-studio-intellisen)

Answer (score 0):

"I want all user profiles that are approved and not deleted "

Just use linq and try not to recreate SQL... Have to guess a bit the relations but you will get the picture

```
Var x= From up in db.UserProfiles 
         where up.aspnet_User.aspnet_Membership.IsApproved  == true &&
          (! up.Isdeleted == true)
         select up;
```

or to mimic a Coalesce

```
 Var x = From up in db.UserProfiles 
             where up.aspnet_User.aspnet_Membership.IsApproved  == true &&
             (up.Isdeleted == false || up.Isdelete == null )
             select up;
```

(i would do the ! False in this case, because null have some issues apparently - however i never experienced them you can look at [LINQ query - null date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2509044/532498))

Comment: Hm. I appreciate your time on this, I got what you are saying, thanks. However, I failed to convey my bigger picture to you, my chunk above is just a chunk in a bigger query with lots of other joins. My main question is, can we rely on linq to use 'constant' attributes in anonymous classes while joining. My fault, for not painting the entire picture, but I think I know what's going on, will post the reason for the issue when I am back tomorrow.

Comment: Also, I realize I typed 'not' twice mistakenly. so the ! in your for query shouldn't be there.

Comment: -Your first option is not correct(your edit where you removed the ! caused the totally opposite meaning now). Result should include everything that is not deleted; NOT everything that is deleted.