# Linq to SQL multiple foreign keys to same primary key - visual studio intellisense

Tags: linq-to-sql

Sorry. Couldn't think of a better title. Here is my dilemma. my sql tables below:

```
create table MainTable (UserId,somefields);
create table SecondaryTable(pkid, somefields, UserId,CreatedBy,UpdatedBy);
```

UserId,CreatedBy,UpdatedBy are foreign keys referencing MainTable(UserId). 
Now as part of my linq queries, I routinely(wrongly) do things like

```
dbContext.SecondaryTable.Where(r=>r.MainTable.someOtherChainingHere)
```

The point is, I always assumed(wrongly) that Linq would automatically pick the best match among possible fields. Since UserId is the common field, I thought it would refer to it. But it is not. I seems to go by alphabetical order. Meaning, in Visual Studio Intellisense when I

```
dbContext.SecondaryTable.Where(r=>r.
```

I see MainTable,MainTable1,MainTable2 as my possible options. 
How would I know the right one to pick among those three???? I apologize if I am not being more articulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I've done in is by using partial classes to add "programmer friendly names" like this:

```
public partial class secondarytable
    {

        public maintable createdByUser{
            get
            {
                return this._maintable1.Entity;
            }
            set
            {
                this._maintable1= value;
            }
        }
```

etcetera for the remaining references.

I've chosen not to do any manual changes to the DBML so I can always recreate it from scratch.

You just need to be carefull that when you change the DBML and the foreign key definition, that the 1,2,3 are still referencing the right table.

Good question btw. I am very curious to see better options!

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for a config change for intellisense that would magically handle this sort of thing, so I am wrong.
I guess the other (obvious) option would be to rewrite my query more explicitly and avoid ambiguities altogether.